# Javascript form validation, too many if statements?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have a form with five elements, `firstName`, `lastName`, `username`, `password` and `passwordConfirmation`

```
var errors = [];
var errorsText = [];


function generateError(messageText, elementIdentifier) {
var messageText = messageText;
var elementIdentifier = elementIdentifier;
errors.push(elementIdentifier);
errorsText.push(messageText);
return false;
}



function validateRegistrationForm(firstName, lastName, username, password, passwordConfirmation) {
formReset();
//alert("validateRegistrationForm() has been called");

var firstName = firstName;
//alert("First Name = \'" + firstName + "\'");
var lastName = lastName;
//alert("Last Name = \'" + lastName + "\'");
var username = username;
//alert("Username = \'" + username + "\'");
var password = password;
//alert("Password = \'" + password + "\'");
var passwordConfirmation = passwordConfirmation;
//alert("Password Confirmation = \'" + passwordConfirmation + "\'");

if ( ( firstName == null ) || ( firstName == "" ) ) {
    //alert("//firstname hasn't been filled out");

    generateError("You must provide a First Name", "firstName");
} 

if ( ( lastName == null ) || ( lastName == "" ) ) {
    //lastname hasn't been filled out
    generateError("You must provide a Last Name", "lastName");
}

if ( ( username == null ) || ( username == "" ) ) {
    //username hasn't been filled out
    generateError("You must enter a Username", "username");
}

if ( ( password == null ) || ( password == "" ) ) {
    //password hasn't been filled out
    generateError("You haven\'t entered a password", "password");
}

if ( ( passwordConfirmation == null ) || ( passwordConfirmation == "" ) ) {
    //passwordconfirmation hasn't been filled out
    generateError("You haven\'t confirmed your password", "passwordConfirmation");
}

validatePassword(password, passwordConfirmation);

}
```

Is there a better way to handle all of the `if statements`?

Comment: Although perhaps slightly out of the scope of this question, a number of JS frameworks offer the option to define validation methods/messages on 'models' and a standard way to display responses to validation

Comment: Thanks @dougajmcdonald but for this project I am not using any libraries like jQuery etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like something you could use the [Logical OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_%28.7C.7C%29) short circuit for

```
function validateRegistrationForm(firstName, lastName, username, password, passwordConfirmation) {
    formReset();
    firstName || generateError("You must provide a First Name", "firstName");
    lastName || generateError("You must provide a Last Name", "lastName");
    username || generateError("You must enter a Username", "username");
    password || generateError("You haven\'t entered a password", "password");
    passwordConfirmation || generateError("You haven\'t confirmed your password", "passwordConfirmation");
    validatePassword(password, passwordConfirmation);
}
```

Comment: Could you edit it to show me how I would go about only calling the validatePassword if the password and passwordConfirmation have been filled out please.

Comment: I sorted it out, thanks for your input. It works, just what I needed for the time being.

Comment: @Mike Sorry was afk. That could be done by `password && passwordConfirmation && validatePassword(password, passwordConfirmation)`.

Answer (score 5):

Consider creating a map of fields names and error messages:

```
var errorMessages = {
  firstName:"You must provide a First Name",
  lastName: "You must provide a Last Name",
  username: "You must enter a Username",
  password: "You haven't entered a password",
  passwordConfirmation: "You haven\'t confirmed your password"
};
```

And maybe a small helper function for throwing errors conditionally:

```
var assertIsFilled = function(name, value) {
  if(!value) {
    generateError(errorMessages[name], name);
  }
});
```

That'll clean up your validation function nicely:

```
function validateRegistrationForm(firstName, lastName, username, password, passwordConfirmation) {
  formReset();
  assertIsFilled("firstName", firstName);
  assertIsFilled("lastName", lastName);
  assertIsFilled("username", username);
  assertIsFilled("password", password);
  assertIsFilled("passwordConfirmation", passwordConfirmation);

  validatePassword(password, passwordConfirmation);
}
```

Comment: You got my +1 for the use of an Object to store strings; always good because it means you can easily swap languages around.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than checking for both `null` and the `empty string`, you can just check to see if the value is truthy.

```
if (firstName) { 
 // value is truthy 
}
```

Or rather you can use the following,

```
if (!firstName) {
 // value is non-truthy
 generateError("You must provide a First Name", "firstName");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like this? :

```
jQuery(":input").bind("blur change",function(){
     if(jQuery(this).val()===null || jQuery(this).val()===""){
     generateError();
    }
})
```

Also you can filter out the inputs you don't need validated this way.

Raw JS version:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for (var i=0, len=inputs.length; i<len; i++){
    if (inputs[i].type == 'text'){      
        inputs[i].onclick = function(){ 
              if(this.value===null || this.value===""){
                generateError();
              }       

        }
//same for onBlur
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not using jQuery, I know it is something I could look into but for this project I am not using it.

Comment: You should be able to do the same with raw JS but it would be a bit more verbose. I've updated the post a bit with a raw JS version which should work